# breaks in histogram

Tags: r, histogram

In excel when we plot a histogram , we can define bins, and values that are greater than the bin values are shown as "more" in the histogram. Can we do similar kind of thing in R (using the base plotting system).

Answer (score 1):

As Roman said you can use the cut function,

```
r<-cut(x,breaks=c(0,50,Inf),levels=c("lev1","lev2")
```

will partition the x into two levels. Then you can draw the histogram using the usual hist command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this means you have to pre-calculate the values yourself. You can use function `cut` to define breaks in your data. The result will be a factor (with bin names as indicators where the split was done). You can then merge factor levels and plot the result.